# Consuming dynamics NAV data using web services in windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, dynamics-nav

I need help on consuming microsoft dynamics nav web service using a windows 10 universal app using C#. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using the service reference to add and use the web service , solution obtained from this link :https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/20/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-c-using-service-reference-code-version/